# Visual Studio 2012 Reference to dll in Library App

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dll

I have a such solution hierarchy:

*Solution* "App"

*project* **App**

*project* **Lib**

For example, if i want to use somedll.dll in **App** and in **Lib** project, i must add references to both projects, but as i understand there must be a way to add .dll only to **Lib** project, so classes from it would be reachable in **App** project. Is there a way to do it? Thank you.

Comment: are you developing a windows phone app?

Comment: Windows 8 "Metro" app

Comment: Your histotry shows you never accept answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have, let say, a logging library that will be used along the whole project, then that library must be referenced everywhere it's members are called.